# In my controller , How to do foreach of my table PageContent and update only to field inside of each record the records

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

i want to update all the records of my table PageContent in my controller.
How to do a foreach or for in order to update all the record of my table but only two field i want to update :

```
fetched.PageContentVisible = false;
fetched.PageContentPhoto = "Submenu" + "-" + item.PageContentId + "-" + item.MenuSubId + "-" + item.PageSectionId;
```

This is the code :

```
 // GET: PageContents/UpdateScript
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateScript()
    {
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            var pageContent = _context.PageContent.Include(p => p.ParentMenuPage).Include(p => p.ParentPageSection);

            using (_context)
            {
                foreach (var item in pageContent)
                {
                    var fetched = _context.PageContent.Find(item.PageContentId);

                    fetched.PageContentPhoto = "PageContent" + "-" + item.PageContentId + "-" + item.MenuSubId + "-" + item.PageSectionId;
                    if (item.PageSectionId == 2)
                    {
                        fetched.PageContentVisible = false;
                    }
                    _context.Entry(fetched).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    
                }
            }
            transaction.Complete();
           
            return View(await pageContent.ToListAsync());
            
        }            

    }
```

but it does not work because of this error :

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
> Object name: 'ApplicationDbContext'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
>
> CateringMilano.Controllers.PageContentsController.UpdateScript() in PageContentsController.cs
> +
> return View(await pageContent.ToListAsync());

thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Would you kindly share your full controller code instead of this two line only. Post your question in reproducible way.

Comment: Hi Md Farid Uddin Kiron, i just updated my question with the code, could you help me to resolve the issue? thank

Comment: It’s because of this this line `applicationDbContext` you are looping on your `DbContext` while the existing connection is already open. This never going to work! Here note that database context should be same but must loop over your `PageContent` content with the same `db context` connection. Though your problem is not reproducible but the [imaginary code would be like this](https://jsfiddle.net/faridkiron/fmhj6b70/1/). Let me if that works then I will post that example

Comment: Hi Md Farid Uddin Kiron
 , thanks for your answer, when i run your code i got this error : An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: A TransactionScope must be disposed on the same thread that it was created.
System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()         :   CateringMilano.Controllers.PageContentsController.UpdateScript() in PageContentsController.cs
+
                return View(await pageContent.ToListAsync());

Comment: Thanks for the update, I see then please try [use updated code here](https://jsfiddle.net/faridkiron/fmhj6b70/4/)

Comment: If that also does't work then you can use `update` to update your current item like this way `_context.Update(item);` instead of `_context.SaveChanges();` which is opning new db connection pool under same connection.

Comment: Hi, no it does not works with  await _context.Update(fetched);     : An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: A TransactionScope must be disposed on the same thread that it was created.
System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()       CateringMilano.Controllers.PageContentsController.UpdateScript() in PageContentsController.cs
+
                transaction.Complete();

Comment: Hi, i  did your code  but with _context.SaveChanges(); the db tablehas been updated but when the script end, the page is loaded wit an error :
  dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed() HOW TO RESOLVE?

Comment: To handle that make another view like this `return RedirectToAction("New View Name");` and redirect to that view instead of this `return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());`

Comment: How to dispode the context? because apparently this is the problem...

Comment: Use `_context.Dispose()` at the end of your `database read-write` operation. After this line `_context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Hi, if i add this lineof code i get this error : An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(bool setTimeout, out bool more)

Comment: Update your question with full  latest code what are you up to now then can suggest

Comment: Hi, i just update the code used and the error, the db table has been update but there is something missing in order to charge the page UpdateScript, which is the list of the items  my table PageContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment you could try below code snippet:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateScript()
    {
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            var pageContent = _context.PageContent.Include(p => p.ParentMenuPage).Include(p => p.ParentPageSection);

            using (_context)
            {
                foreach (var item in pageContent)
                {
                    var fetched = _context.PageContent.Find(item.PageContentId);

                    fetched.PageContentPhoto = "PageContent" + "-" + item.PageContentId + "-" + item.MenuSubId + "-" + item.PageSectionId;
                    if (item.PageSectionId == 2)
                    {
                        fetched.PageContentVisible = false;
                    }
                    _context.Entry(fetched).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    _context.SaveChanges();

                }
            }
            transaction.Complete(); // Here already your transaction completed,so this line will not work await pageContent.ToListAsync()

            return RedirectToAction("GetUpdatedPageContent"); // Redirect to new View and there you can read the new data and return the view like below

        }

    }
```

### Note

On the new view read your new updated data and return this value to view. which will resolve your problem. See the example below:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateScript()
    {
        var pageContent = _context.PageContent.Include(p => p.ParentMenuPage).Include(p => p.ParentPageSection);
        return View(pageContent); // Redirect this view finally
    }
```

### Reason of error

As you have completed your `scope` here `transaction.Complete()` so after that you cannot do anything because the db connection is already closed for this scope. So you cannot access this `await pageContent.ToListAsync()` any more.

This is why you are getting this error. Please consider that.

Comment: Hi, this code does not works : New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.